# Default destructor freeing an array member of a class, c++

Tags: c++, arrays, class, destructor

Say I have the following classes:

```
class A {};

Class C {
private:
    A a[10];
};

int main() {
    C c;
}
```

Will this code cause a memory leak? As in, will the default destructor that the compiler will define for the C class free the memory of the array of A objects successfully?

I tried to check myself but I couldn't figure out how to run valgrind on OSX 10.7...

Comment: @Stan: Look at the code, `A` seems empty indeed. However, that does not have any influence on the leakiness.

Comment: @phresnel - I see. I just wondered if azphare left out something in `A`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will not leak. If you want to make sure, put a debug statement in the destructor of `A`.

EDIT: simple example...

```
#include <iostream>

class A 
{
public:
  A() { std::cout << "A::A()" << std::endl; }
  ~A() { std::cout << "A::~A()" << std::endl; }
};

Class C {
private:
    A a[10];
};

int main() {
    C c;
}
```

Now compiling and running the above example, should produce 10 instances of the first debug statement and 10 instances of the second debug statement. The last 10 statements are produced when the 10 instances of `A` are destroyed (which is done automatically for you - hence the term *automatic storage*, when they go out of scope - in this case, that is when the instance of `C` [which owns them] goes out of scope [at the end of `main`].)

Comment: Okay, since the memory for the array is allocated on the stack, it is freed when main() finishes executing (right?) Could you show me what you mean by a debug statement in the destructor of A? I'm not sure I understand...

Comment: `A::~A(){std::clog << "Destructing an A at" << static_cast<void*>(this) << std::endl;}`. That will prove all 10 A objects inside `C c` are destroyed.

Answer (score 2):

No it won't cause a memory leak. The classes doesn't use **new** at all so the there is no memory dynamically allocated in the heap.

Answer (score 2):

Memory leak issue arises only for dynamic memory allocation. For **automatically** allocated memory (usually on stack or data segment) there is never a memory leak.